# Passing json to google charts via ajax - how to format the date

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I am assembling my json server-side and passing it back to javascript.

`var chart_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response);`

I have a problem with the dates - how do I properly format it? It works as string, but there are some nuances that I need to use; and I need to format my date as date. 
ISSUE: google chart does not work when I try to use date type. it is giving me an error: `c[qe] is not a function`

I created two fiddles to show my issue. Hopefully it will help:

This is working example with `STRING` instead of `DATE`: http://jsfiddle.net/fd3wyuao/1/

This is `NOT`working example with `DATE`: http://jsfiddle.net/p7n62b8j/1/

Please advise.

```
{
  "cols":[
    {
      "id":"",
      "label":"Date",
      "type":"date"
    },
    {
      "id":"",
      "label":"Accounts",
      "type":"number"
    }
  ],
  "rows":[
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 10, 20)"
        },
        {
          "v":3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 10, 21)"
        },
        {
          "v":1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 10, 23)"
        },
        {
          "v":2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 10, 24)"
        },
        {
          "v":1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 10, 27)"
        },
        {
          "v":4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 10, 29)"
        },
        {
          "v":1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 11, 03)"
        },
        {
          "v":1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 11, 04)"
        },
        {
          "v":2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 11, 05)"
        },
        {
          "v":1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 11, 06)"
        },
        {
          "v":1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 11, 12)"
        },
        {
          "v":3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 11, 14)"
        },
        {
          "v":2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 11, 17)"
        },
        {
          "v":1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 11, 18)"
        },
        {
          "v":1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "c":[
        {
          "v":"new Date(2014, 11, 19)"
        },
        {
          "v":2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it :

`var res0       ='{ "cols": [{"id":"","label":"Date","type":"date"},{"id":"","label":"Accounts","type":"number"}],"rows": [{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 10, 20)"},{"v":3}]}, {"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,10,21)"},{"v":1}]}] } ';`

from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference (end of the first LONG table)

Previous answers but not the subject :

You may use `new Date("2014-10-21")`

And for more you can do `new Date("2014-10-21 10:00:00")` to setup this date at 10:00 AM

Maybe using the `new Date("2014-10-21").valueOf()` same as `+new Date("2014-10-21")` do the thing.
Or maybe a string with `new Date("2014-10-21").toString()` same as `""+new Date("2014-10-21")`

Comment: I added working and not working fiddle in my question